# How to make this kind of color/texture effect in illustrator (for a logo)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, logo, texture

I'm pretty new in Graphic Design and I would like to make something similar to the background of this logo :

[image: https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/003/430/840/large/benoit-leloup-logo-idsp-colowip-001.jpg?1473611695]

link here : https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/003/430/840/large/benoit-leloup-logo-idsp-colowip-001.jpg?1473611695

I'm talking about the degraded color texture like a cut clay.

Thanks !

Comment: For a begginer a good advice would be to get to know the tool you are using. I would advice to look at every outocome of filters.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hey ! The closest is the vitrail effect, are you talking about it? Its a pain to vectorise after it and there are black line around every forms

Answer (score 0):

1. Draw random polygons with the Pen Tool, using snap to grid to get them to line up
2. Fill them with different colours by sampling from a step blend of various colours
3. Group all the polygons
4. Draw a circle over the top
5. Select both the group and circle, and do Object > Clipping Mask > Make

Example

[image]

Comment: Wow !! Thank you so much :))

Answer (score 0):

Make a few hundred pixels wide selection in Photoshop (see NOTE1) to an empty layer and fill it with a gradient:

[image]

Apply filter Pixelate > Crystallize:

[image]

Copy and paste to Illustrator and trace it to vector. Check how many colors you need:

[image]

Apply Object > Live Trace > Expand and Ungroup if you need freely editable separate pieces:

[image]

If you watch carefully your examples you see the seams of the pieces have a kind of glow. It's a typical artifact when exactly fitting seams occur in vector images which are exported from Illustrator. The exported version is finally a bitmap image and to avoid jagginess Illustrator has made the seams partially transparent. It can be avoided by making the pieces overlap for ex. by inserting a stroke. In this case the effect can be wanted.

NOTE1: You can as well work in Illustrator the whole job. There's also effect Pixelate > Crystallize. It generates a raster image as an effect which must be expanded and traced to get a real vector. Start by drawing a circle or other shape and fill it with a gradient.

Comment: Thank you :)) !!